# Mapping Actions to a Node-based editor using Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, nodes, unity3d-editor

My question revolves around how to get behaviours described by a node-based editor to map to actions in-game. I've searched for several weeks about how to do this but can't find anything. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd be really grateful!

I don't know the best way to ask this question - I don't want to overload the question with what I've done, so I'll elaborate a bit below, as best I can:

I currently have a custom node-based editor I wrote for Unity, which I use to graphically edit the behaviour of bosses and NPCs. It looks like this (with the right-click menu shown):
[image: Node-based behaviour editor]

I did find a way to get this behaviour working in-game, but it feels wonky and I'm wondering if there's a better way.

The way it works is there are two objects to be serialized per node object. I currently have these setup as scriptable objects, though if I were to do this again I'd create my own kind of serialization. These two objects are:

- The Node in the editor window, containing editor scripts
- The associated in-game action, to be loaded by the NPC at runtime

This creates a bit of mess in the file structure, as well as the amount of script files I need. On top of this, it's a bit tricky to manage cases where multiple actions are being performed simultaneously, and I need to change the NPC's state (e.g. phase1 to phase2 of a boss fight), which sounds to me like a design issue.

I'd be happy to share source code or more screenshots, if at all necessary. What I'm looking for is a way to approach something like this in a structured way that allows scalability for other projects (e.g. NPC behaviour for an RTS)

Comment: For the file issue, it looks like you should really target a single file for the layout of nodes. Have you tried a single scriptable object that contains a list of serializable objects? That should collapse your files down to a single scriptable object per node layout. If you are talking about the actual scripts for implementing the various actions, I would expect there to be a runtime-side class and an editor-side class for each.

Comment: @BJennings Thanks for the reply - The issue I had with a single file with sub-assets is that I'm auto-saving the node editor, and I want to save/delete scriptable objects as they're added/removed. I couldn't find a neat way to delete an asset if it's a sub-asset in a scriptable object file. This is a big reason I wanted to steer away from scriptable objects and handle serialization myself. The runtime-side does end up in a single file however - I'm saving that OnLostFocus()

I was considering even having a single scriptable object per node+action pair, not sure if its possible. Thanks again!